# htaccess rewrite doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an index.php file, with the following lines in it:

```
if(isset($_GET["page"]))
{
    $page=$_GET["page"];
    setcookie("page",$page,time()+315360000);
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE["page"]))
{
    $page=$_COOKIE["page"];
}
else
{
    $page="stock";
}
```

It's a simple page handler script, if you don't have the variables in your URL, the last viewed page will be opened.

Now I want to rewrite the URLs with a .htaccess file, and I have really strange results.
My webpage was hosted on a server like www.host.com/directory/index.php

Basically, I want the URLs look like www.host.com/directory/$page

The .htacces file was placed to the "directory", and have the following lines in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

My problem:
If the system can find a file based on the $page variable, it will be included. If the file doesn't exists, an error page will be displayed. Now, on the error page I echoed out the $page variable, and it is "index.php".

What is wrong with my code, and how can I fix it? I've never written any .htaccess before...
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is looping, you need to add some conditions to prevent this from happening:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: With yyour first snippet, some .js and .css can not load properly, but the second one works like a charm! Thank you!